# Find multiples of given values with minimum mismatch in making desired total number

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to google sheets and question which I am asking is typical math question.

I have a value (in d3) which refers to total gram of gas required, now I have to release this much (d3) gas from number of gas Cans. Gas Cans are of two kinds bigger one contains 680 grams gas and small one contains 454 grams of gas.

Now once we open the gas CAN then whole gas will be released mean to say that we cannot release part portion of gas however we can minimize wastage if we use exact (or near to exact) amount of gas required by using some big cans and some small cans. I have worked hard and found a way (see in c3:c5 and also see in b12:c12) but that is too long & that has been shown in below mentioned link.

Now I want total no. of big cans and small cans in d4 & d5 with a formula so that same criteria can be applied to all values.

It has been explained in detail with example in following link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZiKMqb33kDSOIduBMayZ0NMqibcvMF-UBYYvn7VVBs/edit

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For D4 you can have `=FLOOR(FLOOR(G3/680)+MOD(G3, 680)/454)` and for D5 you can have `=IF(G3 > G4*680, CEILING(MOD((G3-G4*680)/454, 454)), 0)`.

Not sure if it will work for all cases though, so make sure you do some testing. In D4, it does the same thing you did where you find the whole number of *big* cans. It then also calculates if the remainder is larger than one *small* can, then another big can will be added (it is effectively your "> 66.76" calculation). In D5, the remaining grams are calculating after taking into account how many *big* cans there already are. If there are remaining grams, then one *small* can would be calculated. If there are enough *big* cans to hold the gas, no *small* cans are necessary. It includes some calculation, but `=IF(G3 > G4*680, 1, 0)` should work the same, since there should only be one or zero *small* cans.

Comment: Thanks this works fine on google spreadsheet but I want to use this in open office where it is not working, can you please modify it for open office also

Comment: I think the only difference in OpenOffice is that you need to add a multiple to round by for `FLOOR` and `CEILING`. Try `=FLOOR(FLOOR(G3/680, 1)+MOD(G3, 680)/454, 1)` for D4 and `=IF(G3 > G4*680, CEILING(MOD((G3-G4*680)/454, 454), 1), 0)` for D5.

Comment: Woops, I didn't realize I was working in the G column this whole time. Did you make sure that you're referencing the correct cells? Aside from that, I can't think of anything else, as it works fine for me.

Comment: I have corrected this and wrote d in place of G, you can see this in spreadsheet